# aspose pdf: How to select a radio button in XFA?

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I am trying to update field in a XFA pdf file. I am able to do so for text fields:

```
XFA xfa = doc.getForm().get_xfa();
xfa.set_Item("field", "value");
```

How to make a radio button selection this way?

Comment: Would you please create a topic in dedicated support forum of Aspose.PDF (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) along with your sample PDF file? It is recommended approach to address and communicate such issues related to Aspose APIs. We will check it and assist you accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AsadAli, created the topic on forum. Thanks.